# how may I update a mongo nested field with another mongo nested field?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql

I am trying to update a nested with a different nested field:

```
db.projects.update({
  "projectSteps.uploadToCreate.status": 1
}, //no started   {   $set: {    
"projectSteps.ownerReviewandApproval._id": ObjectId(),
"projectSteps.ownerReviewandApproval.documents": projectSteps.differentStepField.documents, < -help "projectSteps.ownerReviewandApproval.name": 'ownerReviewandApproval',
"projectSteps.ownerReviewandApproval.status": NumberInt(1),
//}
}, {
multi: true
});
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is this you given here, "projectSteps.ownerReviewandApproval.documents": projectSteps.differentStepField.documents, < -help "projectSteps.ownerReviewandApproval.name": 'ownerReviewandApproval',

Comment: Is this correct?